# Entity Framework - How to return single entity without related objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Im using EF6, DB First, in a MVC project with **LazyLoading turned off**.
However upon updating some of the entities properties, I found that upon updating an entities related objects in a function in the same context, that by the time I return the single entity, it also contains the related objects that I had updated. **I would like to return the single entity only.**

So my question is, is there a better way to "clean off" the related entities other than creating a new context and retrieving the entity again? Or would you update the related entities in a different context? Or is there a cleaner method than these?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand, what do you mean by "clean off"? and what is "update entity" function? have you overridden update behavior? are you referring to "attach"? is it code first? db first? some code maybe?

Comment: Hi @user2033402! Thanks for your comment. I added DB First to the question. Update entity simply means its a function that updates the entity: ie, the user changes some existing data and clicks save. In that same update, I also have to update its related entities, so these are then added to the object graph. So by the time i want to simply return the updated single entity, it includes all the related entities i also updated. By clean off, i want to remove/return the entity without its related entities!

Comment: It looks to me like you're solving the wrong problem. If you for example have a `Blog` with an `ICollection<Comment> Comments` property, and you have a context that has recently seen some Comments with Blog_ID 42, then when the context sees a Blog with ID 42 it'll attach the Comment entities to the blog. That's just how the change tracker works. What _problem_ does this attaching cause?

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster, The problem is simply that its returning by json a HUGE graph of related entities, that is not needed and consequently I get an error like "json to big to deserialise"!

Comment: So your actual problem is that you're using Entity Framework data models as data transfer objects, which you shouldn't. Other than explicitly nulling the properties you want, or projecting using `Select()` into a new, perhaps anonymous type, I don't think there's a built-in solution.

Comment: You are sending Json around. Are you using a web based user interface?

Comment: @jvanrhyn how is that relevant? Are you using a Visual Basic GUI?

Comment: Well, best practice is to serialze/deserialze view models and not the actual EF entities. Thus sending to you client, just what it needs.

Comment: if you are using a microsoft web based solution like mvc, webapi or WCF,you can use data attributes in order not to serialize a property to json when returning it. if you are usin Newtsoft JSON the attribute is [JsonIgnore], for mvc\webapi without this nuget its [ScriptIgnore] and for wcf you just dont put a [DataMember] Attribute

Comment: hi @jvanrhyn - I am using web based - MVC. I updated the question. Thanks for your input everyone

Comment: Turn ProxyCreationEnabled off as well for helping serialization.

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster, can you explain or send me a link to what you mean when you say im using EF data models as data transfer objects? Is it by the way i program? Or is it a setting of some sort? Thanks so much.

Comment: Generally you should separate your database from your API. So create new classes that hold the data you want to return from the API (Data Transfer Objects or DTOs), and map between your data entities and your DTOs.

Comment: Hi everyone, very valid points, thanks heaps. I will select into a viewmodel and return the viewmodel instead of the EF entity. Interestingly, I usually do that, but this viewmodel was going to be so similar to the EF Entity that I was returning the EF entity. The only difference were 2 related entities that wern't needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are expecting Entity Framework to behave in a way that it is not intended to do.  Based on your comments and question, it seems that in the same context you are touching a parent entity and one or more of its children entities.  As a result, the change tracker is putting all of that together for you.

Your second issue is that your code return probably looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Stuff(){
    //MyEntityFrameworkClass is an autogenerated Entity Framework 
    //object that represents a table in your database
    List<MyEntityFrameworkClass> items = db.MyEntityFrameworkClass.ToList();
    Return Json(items);
}
```

This is bad because you are returning everything in the database for each of these items including any of the related entities that have been attached.  What happens in these instances:

- You don't need to return every single column
- You want to return some auto calculated columns not included in the entity
- You need values from multiple entities

This is where View Models (or Data Transfer Objects) come into play.  Create a model specifying **EXACTLY** what your client needs and nothing more.

```
public class MyApiModel(){
   public string Name {get;set;}

   public int SomethingElse {get;set;}

   //Computed property in our view model
   //Lets say anything greater than 2 is valid
   public bool IsValid => SomethingElse > 2;
}
```

Now you should return a List (or whatever) of this type of object.

```
public ActionResult Stuff(){
    List<MyApiModel> items = db.MyEntityFrameworkClass.Select(x=>new MyApiModel{
          //Notice I am not setting the isvalid property
          //Its computed, class takes care of returning proper value
          Name = x.MyNameColumn, 
          SomethingElse = x.MyOtherColumn
    }.ToList();
    Return Json(items);
}
```